# container alignment with bootstrap3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to right-align few bootstrap 3 container in a simple way but... it was not so simple... the long story short... have a look at [this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/m5GWYl7ooL): I would like to have the test box right aligned with the navbar right border. Initially I just solved the problem using the bootstrap grid but then I realized that because of the z-indez:1 (which is needed), I was no more able to click on the left of the text box... And I found out that I cannot put a container on top of the background (also if the container span only the last 2 column of the bootstrap grid) without loosing the capability to interact with it... I hope it's clear and someone can give a hint on how to solve my problem...
Thanks

---

The code is right here:

### Bootply  ##:[this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/m5GWYl7ooL)

### HTML

```
<div class="container myMapNavBar">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    this is the navbar
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="container" id="myScrollBox">
  this is a test box
</div>
```

### Css

```
.myMapNavBar {
    position: absolute;
    left:0; right:0;
    top: 15px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#myScrollBox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    width: 380px;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);  
}
```

Comment: Show us your partial code (jsfiddle)

Comment: @LuisP.A. he has ever shared his code (bootply), But I don't really understand what is expected with this kind of code....

Comment: @YenneInfo..yes, you are right..the text was so compact that i miss it

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/DTeYL00jsp ?

Comment: I knew it was not simple to explain it... anyhow, have a look at the bootply link. I used on the "myScrollBox" css the following instruction: "right: 30px;". This is not what I want. I'd like to have the right border of the navbar and the right border of the "test box" aligned... also when I change the window dimension (and because of the bootstrap responsiveness the navbar dimension change...). How can I align them?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: ok. Panto suggestion is exactly what I need but it didn't work... the real problem (and sorry for this) arise from the fact that there is a leaflet map on the background and the user has to interact with it (and this is why I need the z-index)... Have a look a this bootply which show the real problem: http://www.bootply.com/45nq5xQxD5 the text box has to move to the right... aligned with the navbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove absolute positions and and pull-right class on new div that is inside container and wraps the test box.

here is the [bootplay](http://www.bootply.com/DcR1auwDQY)

Comment: Thanks Panto... it's exactly what I need but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem... see comment above

Comment: practically you need to put text box in same .container class so it follows the witdh and set right:0px so the aboslute positioned element will float to right.
here is the bootply [link](http://www.bootply.com/52GomxNivQ)